# Drawing a square in an Argand diagram

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

Suppose that ABCD is a quadrilateral (labelled anticlockwise) with its vertices being represented by complex number a,b,c,d respectively.

The conditions for ABCD to be a square are (a-b)=(d-c) and i(a-c)=(b-d) [i.e. edges are parallel and diagonals intersect at right angle].

Why is the second condition not sufficient? surely it is only met if the two diagonals are perpendicular and have equal length; and ABCD is therefore a square (without showing that the first condition is true)?

Comment: If the diagonals do not intersect in their middle, you could also obtain a [kite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(geometry)). If you want a square, you have to constrain the diagonals to intersect in their middle, or add some other constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the comment, it could be a kite.

An explicit example, let $a=2,b=i,c=-2,d=-3i,$

then we have

$$i(a-c)=4i=b-d$$

but

$$a-b=2-i$$ and

$$d-c=-3i-2 \neq a-b$$
[image]